# Общее меню и подвал для многостраничного сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка

Вовремя осознав, что имея сайт из ~30 страничек, редактировать общие меню и подвал для каждой страницы по отдельности мягко говоря не совсем умно, я озадачился вопросом единовременных правок. Таким образом мне нужен метод запихивания html-фрагмента кода в другой html-файл, чтобы редактируя один фрагмент кода, я мог менять контент на всех страницах, где этот фрагменты присутствует( по крайней мере в моем понимании это выглядит так). Я не знаю php и поэтому, натыкаясь на решения из разряда "переведите все .html в .php" и так далее мне становится худо... Метод там вроде не сложный, но неясно как в целом это отразится на верстке, а неизвестность пугает... "Ну так почитай" скажите вы, и обычно я бы так и сделал, но сроки сильно поджимают. От JS  я тоже бесконечно далёк, но если это единственным выход, то прошу объяснение "для самых маленьких, а также какие ещё есть варианты. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Тебе нужен генератор статических сайтов

Comment: `мне нужен метод запихивания html-фрагмента кода в другой html-файл` - если html то только js

Comment: @InDevX здравствуйте, не подскажите как это реализуется на js?

Comment: @Blamy с помощью js вы сможете добавлять элементы только после загрузки страницы, что Вам может не подойти, может быть такой эффект, что страница загрузилась, а потом резко появляется какой-то элемент. Либо же можно скрыть всю страницу, добавить с помощью js элемент, а потом показать всю страницу уже с элементом - это большая задержка рендеринга. Вам нужен шаблон на php.

Comment: https://htmlacademy.ru/tutorial/php/templates почитайте, вы разберетесь, там хорошо расписано

Comment: @highpassion спасибо большое!